# How can I calculate the bearing between two points in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, direction

How can I find the bearing between two points in PostGIS?

Please specify in your answer whether or not the method producing a bearing on the spheroid, or a planar bearing.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### Using ST_Azimuth

Planar bearing can be calculated using [`ST_Azimuth`](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_Azimuth.html):

```
SELECT ST_Azimuth(ST_MakePoint(1,2), 
           ST_MakePoint(3,4))/(2*pi())*360 as degAz,
       ST_Azimuth(ST_MakePoint(3,4), 
           ST_MakePoint(1,2))/(2*pi())*360 As degAzrev

degaz   degazrev
------  ---------
45      225
```

For spherical azimuth (Quoting [potgis-users group](http://www.mail-archive.com/postgis-users@postgis.refractions.net/msg04711.html)):

> The PostGIS azimuth function seems to
>   use a simple arctan function to
>   determine  azimuth. If you convert
>   your coordinates to a projected
>   coordinate system and  then run the
>   query, your results will be much
>   closer to the FCC site's results.
>   Here is a quick conversion to UTM Zone
>   31:

```
select degrees(azimuth(
'POINT(634714.442133176 5802006.052402816)',
'POINT(634731.2410598891 5801981.648284801)'
));
```

> which yields an azimuth of
>   145.457858825445.  Points in the center of the UTM  zone, or a more
>   suitable projection would give better
>   results.

### Using trigonometric functions and ST_distance_sphere

This is the solution I've chosen when I had to deal with this problems, mainly for legacy reasons (I had a Python function which calculates the azimuth). First, we need to find a function that would tell us the exact distance between two points. [Quoting the postgis manual](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-1.3/ch06.html):

> ST_distance_sphere(point, point)
>   Returns linear distance in meters
>   between two lat/lon points. Uses a
>   spherical earth and radius of 6370986
>   meters. Faster than
>   distance_spheroid(), but less
>   accurate. Only implemented for points.

Measure the Longitude and Latitude distance between the points, and use the `arctan` function to retrieve the angle.

Comment: I'll try to post the python code later, and perhaps make some comparisons between the methods - If I can find that legacy code...

Comment: Can you clarify on how you go from a distance to an angle with `atan`?  My trigonmetry is a little hazy...

Answer (score 12):

For anyone coming across this question now - PostGIS supports ST_Azimuth on geography (spheroid) as of 2.0.0.